# C++ Window Message Loop, can't catch messages

Tags: winapi, window

First of all the, here is the important part of my code:

```
MSG msg;
bool done = false;
ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
while (!done)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
             done = true;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the second "if" statement actually never catches the WM_QUIT message and that therefore my message loop never ends. Actually I was not able to catch any messages using "if" statements in this loop. Using the Visual Studio 2013 debugger, I tried to look at the values of msg.message and compared them to a list of available window messages. I was not able to find any value I got in that list.

Do I not understand the concept of a message loop, or is there any other mistake in this code?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the above code, so either you're not posting the quit message at all, posting it to the wrong place, or some part of your message handling code runs its own message loop and throws it away.

Comment: Make sure you call PostQuitMessage() when you close your main window (catch WM_CLOSE and/or WM_DESTROY and call PostQuitMessage() from there)

Answer (score 0):

Stefan had the answer in one of the comments.

My problem was that I assumed that "DefWindowProc" calls PostQuitMessage() but it does not. Adding that call to my WNDPROC solved the problem. Thanks for the help.